# Opencart 2.3 new admin module creation, help wanted

Tags: opencart

I created a new simple module for OC2.3, that gets some data from OC product_special table.

I'm stacked a little bit and i am getting always blank screen when refresh the module template.
What is my false call and can't grab values from the model query?

So my controller file placed in admin/controller/extension/module, named     SpecialPrices.php contains bellow:

```
    <?php
   class ControllerExtensionModuleSpecialprices extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

   public function index() {

   ..............................

    }

// My new function

   public function myFunction() {

        $this->load->language('extension/module/SpecialPrices');
        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
        $this->load->model('extension/module/SpecialPrices');

        $products = $this->model_extension_module_SpecialPrices->getProductSpecials($data);

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                    'price'       => $product_info['price']

                );
            }

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
        $data['text_title'] = $this->language->get('text_title');
        $data['text_product_id'] = $this->language->get('text_product_id');
        $data['text_price'] = $this->language->get('text_price');

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');


        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module   /SpecialPrices', $data));

    }

   ...........
```

2. My model file in admin/model/extension/module named SpecialPrices.php contains...

   ```
       public function getProductSpecials($data) {

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX ."product_special` ";
       $query = $this->db->query($sql);
       return $query->rows;
       }
   ```
3. In my template SpecialPrices.tpl, created in path admin/view/template/extension/module, trying to grab values from above query

   ```
   <?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>

   <div id="content">
   <div class="page-header"> 
   .......
   <?php echo $product_id; ?>
   <?php echo $price; ?>
   .........
   ```

   4. in admin/language/en-gb/extension/module there is SpecialPrices.php

// Text
$_['text_extension']   = 'Extensions';
$_['text_success']     = 'Success: You have inserted Mass Special Prices to products!';
$_['text_edit']        = 'Edit Mass Special Prices Module';

Answer (score 0):

In first sight there is the error you left spaces after `module`:

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module   /SpecialPrices', $data));
```

Must be:

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/SpecialPrices', $data));
```

What errors you receive in error log?
In controller file you should place your code to `public function index() {//your code}`or call your function somewhere.. if you have created it. I do not see where you are calling it.
 If you have array of your data which call in tpl you should do it like this:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>

<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>
<?php echo $product['price']; ?>
<?php }?>
```

OK. edited and working:
controller `mymodule.php`:

```
 <?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleMymodule extends Controller {

  public function index() {

        $this->load->language('extension/module/mymodule');
        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
        $this->load->model('extension/module/mymodule');

        $products = $this->model_extension_module_mymodule->getProductSpecials();

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                    'price'       => $product['price']

                );
            }

            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
        $data['text_title'] = $this->language->get('text_title');
        $data['text_product_id'] = $this->language->get('text_product_id');
        $data['text_price'] = $this->language->get('text_price');




       $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/mymodule', $data));
    }

 }
```

model... `mymodule.php`:

```
 <?php
 class ModelExtensionModuleMymodule extends Model {
 public function getProductSpecials() {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX ."product_special` ";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->rows;
    }
 }
```

`mumodule.tpl`:

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
<div class="container-fluid">
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>

<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>
<?php echo $product['price']; ?>
<?php }?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

After you add files do not forget set permissions in admin>setting>usergroup>  Administrator

Comment: Yes right, is my typing error in my question, the path is OK in tpl file. The "Errors List" is still blank as in the tpl page . I suspect the problem is in controller when i load the model .

Comment: where you calling your function? `public function myFunction()` why just place your code to `public function index() {` and check does it show?

Comment: I did it firstly but had no luck. So I created second function so I call it directly from url, like admin/index.php.....myFunction...

Comment: have edited your code in my first answer... code working.

Comment: OK thanks, i wil try later.  The "mumodule.tpl"  must be mymodule.tpl i guess.

Comment: yes must be mymodule.tpl... you are right. just mistyping

Comment: Thanks a lot  K.B. it works finally. You save my day. Thanx for your time! :-)

Comment: And my last question, if i need to grab values between 2 dates from special table how the controller is configured?